# Difficulty adding custome grains in Salt

Tags: python, salt-stack

I am trying to add custom grains (in salt-stack) to minions by adding a python script into the _grains sub-directory in my file_roots directory [according to the Salt manual here](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/targeting/grains.html) .

My approach is to have the script read-in a text file and parse the data into lists in a dictionary and load them as grains (called roles in this case).

my roles_file looks like this:

```
appserver:minion1.example,minion2.example,minion3.exapmle
webserver:minion1.example
dbserver:minion2.example,minion3.example
```

Which when read into a dictioary will look like this:

```
roles_list {
  appserver: [minion1.example,minion2.example,minion3.example],
  webserver: [minion1.example],
  dbserver: [minino2.example, minion3.example]
}
```

The `set_roles()` function looks like this:

```
def set_roles():

  """
  Set the 'roles' grain based on the host name.
  """

  roles_list = {}
  with open ('roles_file' ,'r') as inf:
    for line in inf:
      role , servers = line.partition(":")[::2]
      roles_list[role] = (servers.rstrip()).split(',')


  grains = {'roles': []}
  hostname = _get_hostname() # defined elsewhere in my file
  logger.debug('{0}'.format(roles_list))

  for role, servers in roles_list.iteritems():

    for server in servers:
      if server == hostname:
        grains['roles'].append(role)

  return grains
```

This does not work and the roles are not loaded! am I missing something here?

How can I debug this better? I know that the `set_roles()` function is called when highstate is executed or when I call `saltutil.sync_grains`. but where can I see output of `logger.debug`?

Comment: First of all, calling a dict a list is just plain confusing, so I would rename roles_list.  I ran a quick test using 'minion1.example' as the host name and it worked. Check the format of 'hostname'.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the grains where not added because the `roels_file` did not exist on the minions. I had to copy the file first to the minions and then run `saltutil.sync_grains` and then it worked.

I am planning to use the roles grains for targeting minions in my environment. So this is obviously a checken-and-egg situation. I need the grains in order to target the minion. and if I make changes to my `roles_file` I need a separate state file (or top file) to update the roles_file on all the minions. Is there a better way for syncing costume grains from a file or a list?

For debugging. I ran the minion in the foreground using the `salt-minion -l debug` command.